# Find the bigger number out of two numbers stored as strings in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am working with a very large input (trying to solve [Next Palindrome problem in SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/)). I need to compare large numbers and find out which is larger.All this without using BigInteger class other i could i have simply parsed BigInteger from the string and compared to get a result.

I tried string.compare(a,b) but the outputs produced suggest that it doesnt support sorting "numeric strings"

Comment: What is the format of the number? Is it an integer, or can it be float? Can it be negative? Can there be leading zeoes?

Comment: No i am working on finding nearest larger palindrome no negatives or decimals or leading zeroes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Find out which string is longer.
2. Fill the beginning of the shorter string with zeroes to match the length of the first string:

```cs
shorterString = shorterString.PadLeft(longerString.Length, '0');
```

3. [Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx).

Update: I assumed that the numbers are integers. If they can be floating-point/decimal, then the algorithm will not be as simple.

Comment: there's no need to to fill string with "0". If it's shorter - than it's smaller

Comment: @ig-melnyk what if the longer string has leading zeroes?

Comment: @ig-melnyk Not if it's already padded. Or a decimal. Or negative

Comment: Compare as in check every digit inside string from Left?

Comment: @Rahul, compare as in [string.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zkcaxw5y(v=vs.110).aspx).